# How to Export large files from dynamic CRM 2013

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to export all the contacts from `Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2013` but since the file is too large, I can only export 10,000 records at a time.

Is there a way to export all the contacts at once? if not then how do I export the rest of the contacts?

I have these contacts sorted by Contact ID which is numeric in number. Currently, it has exported till 10,000 contact IDs. I am not even getting the way through advance search to export the next 10,000 records. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database you could take an export from the FilteredContact table.

Comment: Could you suggest, how to create a view of contacts whose contact ID lies between 10000 and 20000

Comment: Well that is just an advanced find with a filter on the contact ID.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for a few ways of getting around this issue

http://anythingcrm.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/export-10000-rows-out-of-crm-in-excel.html